# Facebook Open Graph Object Post to Timeline

Tags: javascript, facebook, graph

I've followed this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/ multiple times and always get the same result.

I always get this error: (#15) This method must be called with an app access_token. I tried adding the app access_token and I got another error that was saying something like that I can only query for information and not make posts. (I checked in the privacy settings and the app is allowed to post to timeline.) I did make the objects and found nothing wrong when using the facebook debug tool.

I also read this part:

> Why am I getting "This method must be called with an app access_token"
>   error when publishing an action?
>
> - Uncheck the "Require app access token to write" checkbox on the
>     configuration page (hidden under the Advanced section) for your Open
>     Graph action type in the Developer App.

I couldn't find this in app config and I have a feeling that this is old. The code I'm using to make the post is exactly the same as the tutorial:

```
  function postCook()
  {
      FB.api(
        '/me/[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]:cook?recipe=http://fbwerks.com:8000/zhen/cookie.html',
        'post',
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('Error occured');
           } else {
              alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
           }
        });
  }
```

[I did make the appropriate changes of course :)] Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you manage to post regular links or posts?

Comment: I haven't tried that but I got it working with Burton's advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the me here assumes that you are already authenticated. If you are not, you will have to substitute the me with the the fb id of whoever user's timeline you are posting to. That user has to be authenticated in your app. and you have to use the app's access token. So the curl url would look like:

`curl -d "access_token=<app_access_token>" -d "badge=<object_url.(this has to be publicly accessible)>" https://graph.facebook.com/<authenticated_user_fb_id>/<app_namespace>:<action>`

Comment: Thanks! This works except I didn't use the badge part. The only issue is that Facebook isn't grabbing the object information from the meta tags on the webpage. Is that because the object isn't approved and I'm just testing it out?

Comment: My bad. The badge part is actually your object.(that was my object :) ). What you have to do is make sure the metatag og:type matches your object. so here you need `namespace:<your_object>`. So replace badge in my example with your object name and that should = the url to your object page which will contain the the metatags. also, what I did was for the metatag og:url, i used the object url here as well.